# How do I use mark indices with position in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, text-decorations, tikzmark

I am trying to decorate a curve with some arrowheads, there is a way which you could specify the percentage position with steps

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[smooth, decoration = {markings, mark = between positions 0.2 and 0.65 step 0.45 with {\arrow{Stealth[round, scale = 1.5]}}}]
\draw[postaction = {decorate}, dashed] plot coordinates{(0.7, 3) (4, 3) (5, 4)};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I would like to be able use `mark indices` also, like below

```
 \draw plot[mark = x, mark indices = {1, 4, ..., 10, 11, 12, ..., 16, 20}, smooth]
```

However, it seems like `mark indices` would not recognize percentage position. Is there any way to let it accept such parameters?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may not understand your question but you can use the `/.list` key to put some decoration at some positions specified in a list. What I am unsure about is what to make of the numbers you show. I took them to specify the position in units in which the path has length 25, but you can change this, of course.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[smooth, decoration = {markings, mark = between positions 0.2 and 0.65 step 0.45 with {\arrow{Stealth[round, scale = 1.5]}}}]
\draw[postaction = {decorate}, dashed] plot coordinates{(0.7, 3) (4, 3) (5, 4)};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm,percentage mark/.style={ decoration = {markings, mark =
at position #1/25 with {\draw[solid] (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt)
(-2pt,2pt) -- (2pt,-2pt);}}}]
\draw[postaction = {decorate,percentage mark/.list={1, 4, ..., 10, 11, 12, ..., 16, 20}}, dashed] 
(0.7, 3) to[out=0,in=180] (4, 3) to[out=0,in=-120] (5, 4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I slightly changed the way to construct the path one you use throws `dimension to large` errors if you try to add some decoration at points at which the curvature is largish.

Comment: Your solution is fantastic! What I am trying to do is, the `between` function can only specify periodically appearing points, it would fail if the points were random. It would be nice if it could accept a random list as `mark indices` does.

Comment: @zyy Do you have a link to an example that shows how `mark indices` works? The pgfplots manual is very brief on this. I'd be particularly interested in the random list option.

Comment: At page 332 of the [manual](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) of version 3.0.1a. The example it has also decorated some periodic points, but the rest are randomly assigned.

Comment: I am wondering how I could use `smooth` instead of specifying the `in` and `out` angles with your solution.

Comment: @zyy In general you can use smooth but in your example there are `dimension too large` errors one puts marks in some "forbidden" region. This has nothing to do with `percentage mark` but will happen also for your above decoration if you place the arrows at the wrong place. And thanks so much for the documentation of `mark indices`. I am, however, afraid that I still do not understand what the random list will precisely look like. In principle, you can do `percentage mark/.list={20*rnd,20*rnd,20*rnd}`, say, if it were not for the requirement that the marks are to be set in ascending order.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that should be the problem. As for a random list, I would assume `\tikz \draw plot[mark = x, mark indices = {1, 4, 7, 8, 10, 14}, smooth] file {plots/pgfmanual-sine.table};`.

Comment: @zyy You can do the list `percentage mark/.list={1, 4, 7, 8, 10, 14}`, can't you?

Comment: Yes, that works for me, thanks for all you have being doing!

Comment: @marmot The `mark indice` is a function of the sample size. Each point in the sample is indexed.  The first point is indexed 1. The latter is indexed by sample size. For example: when the sample is 25 points, the first point of the sample has an indice equal to 1.  The last point has an indice equal to 25.